# How to disable password or token login on jupyter-notebook with Docker image jupyter/pyspark-notebook

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm running docker with `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook`

```
/usr/local/bin/start-notebook.sh: running hooks in /usr/local/bin/before-notebook.d
/usr/local/bin/start-notebook.sh: running /usr/local/bin/before-notebook.d/spark-config.sh
/usr/local/bin/start-notebook.sh: done running hooks in /usr/local/bin/before-notebook.d
Executing the command: jupyter notebook
[I 12:52:25.086 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 12:52:26.010 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 12:52:26.010 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[I 12:52:26.014 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 12:52:26.014 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.2.0 is running at:
[I 12:52:26.014 NotebookApp] http://bfd1d14020b6:8888/?token=08fe978d71a160ec97096e68a455eda5c06d411d6fe0a666
[I 12:52:26.014 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=08fe978d71a160ec97096e68a455eda5c06d411d6fe0a666
[I 12:52:26.014 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:52:26.019 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-7-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://bfd1d14020b6:8888/?token=08fe978d71a160ec97096e68a455eda5c06d411d6fe0a666
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=08fe978d71a160ec97096e68a455eda5c06d411d6fe0a666
```

I copied the below link, it asked me to input the Password or Token, but when I copied the token showing on the console, it can not be authenticated.

Anyway, I don't want password to login in the notebook. Is there environment or argument passing to `Docker run command`? It is an official image from jupyter, but I cannot see any relevant document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run it with:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook start.sh jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token=''
```

assuming you're in a secured environment - see more info [here](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/recipes.html#run-jupyter-notebook-lab-inside-an-already-secured-environment-i-e-with-no-token).